# Choose of components for a rgb led strip

Tags: power-supply, resistors, led-strip, component-selection

I'm pretty new to electronics. I have some basics from my student life but it is not much.
I want to progress in it and the best way for me is to do it with a project.

Anyway, my goal is to power a RGB strip (as many of you from what I've read online) only using batteries and resistors.

> The strip were given to me, I don't know any of the specs or refs

For now, here is what I found:

- My RGB Led strip is powered with a `5V` supply (written on it)
- There is one input (`5V`) and 3 outputs (R, G and B).

From the USB power supply given, I ran some tests with the provided IR remote and a multimeter to get a table for the corresponding color intensity with the `I`ntensity and the `V`oltage to put.

> Those tests were ran on a 45 LED strip (5050 if I look at the size of the LED)

Now, with this table *(at the bottom)*, I'm capable of getting any color's (or close color) voltage and current.

For example, if I want `#5F9FBF`, I know it is R(95) G(159) B(191)

So for the 45 LEDs of my strip, I need

- Red at `1.69V` and `0.26A`
- Green at `2.33V` and `0.21A`
- Blue at `3.76V` and `0.44A`

For this, I thought about adding resistors to the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnJfIF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**I'm thinking about using 3 batteries of 1.5V in series, I think the brightness can't go full but anyway, I guess it will works as the only time I need 5V is when I want full brightness on a color**

Given, the input of `4.5V` (3 x 1.5V) and `UR = E - Uled`, my guess is

- U*Rred* : `4.5V - 1.69V = 2.81V` (with `0.26A`)
- U*Rgreen*: `4.5V - 2.33V = 2.17V` (with `0.21A`)
- U*Rblue*: `4.5V - 3.76V = 0.74V` (with `0.44A`)

If I go back to my **current** section and use `U=RI` I found

- R*red* `2.81/0.26` = `10 ohms`
- R*green* `2.17/0.21` = `10 ohms`
- R*blue* `0.74/0.44` = `1.7 ohms`

**First thing first, I'm not even sure this is correct... For example, 1.7ohms does not exist, so I need to get close, maybe 2ohms, but this will change the current (and the voltage)... so all the maths are wrong here... I'm a bit lost**

And the second problem is power.

Given the `P=UI` (`P=RII)` formula, with red as example my resistor should handle

PRed `10 * 0.26 * 0.26` = `0.616W`

**But basic resistors can only handle 1/4W, so I need a "bigger" resistor, don't I ? One that can handle `1W` for example. The other solution is to add multiple R in // to divide the current to get 0.250W max per R I guess**

Anyway, if anyone has a clue because I think I am in a kind of snake loop with the calculations here...

---

*Here is the table I found using the multimeter in my led strip*

| Red | Uled (V) | iStrip - 45Led (A) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 256 | 3,98 | 0,71 |
| 224 | 3,56 | 0,63 |
| 192 | 3,12 | 0,54 |
| 160 | 2,66 | 0,44 |
| 128 | 2,2 | 0,35 |
| 96 | 1,69 | 0,26 |
| 64 | 1,15 | 0,16 |
| 32 | 0,6 | 0,08 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |

| Green | Uled (V) | iStrip - 45Led (A) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 256 | 4,37 | 0,62 |
| 224 | 4,04 | 0,54 |
| 192 | 3,66 | 0,46 |
| 160 | 3,25 | 0,39 |
| 128 | 2,79 | 0,29 |
| 96 | 2,33 | 0,21 |
| 64 | 1,79 | 0,14 |
| 32 | 1,25 | 0,06 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |

| Blue | Uled (V) | iStrip - 45Led (A) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 256 | 4,58 | 0,59 |
| 224 | 4,2 | 0,51 |
| 192 | 3,76 | 0,44 |
| 160 | 3,27 | 0,36 |
| 128 | 2,76 | 0,29 |
| 96 | 2,21 | 0,21 |
| 64 | 1,63 | 0,14 |
| 32 | 1,03 | 0,06 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Your understanding seems correct. You can place resistors in series and/or parallel to create new values. For example, 4 * 6.8 Ohm (standard E12 value) in parallel makes 1.7 Ohm and would also spread the power dissipation equally over the 4 resistors.

Comment: Most LED strips use 12V and have 3 LEDs in series and in series with a low power resistor. Why are your LED strips completely different. Please post a link to your LED strips.